# Number of Subspaces that contains other Space

Tags: linear-algebra

In $GF(2)$, How Can I calculate the number of subspaces of dimension $k<w$ that contains a fixed subspace of dimension $k'<w$:

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If $U \subset V$, then there is a bijection between the set of subspaces $W$ of $V$ such that $U \subseteq W$ and the set of subspaces of the quotient space $V/U$.