# How many subsspaces and how calculate them in a Subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $n>0$. Let $V\subset \mathbb{F}_2^n$ a vectorial space. Let $U$ a subspace of $V$.  How many subspaces $W_i \subset V$, at most, I can describe (for example using the basis) such that $U \subset W_i$?

Comment: Number of subspaces of $V/U$?

Comment: You have $V$ as an *element* of $F_2^n$. Do you mean for it to be a subset? a subspace? do you mean for $U$ to be a subspace of $V$? are you trying to maximize over all choices of $V$? over all choices of $U$? You need to do a lot of clarifying to make this a serious question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I have edited my question

Comment: @juaninf you didn't fix the confusing part.  The part that Gerry was commenting on was $V \in \Bbb F^n_2$.  What do you *mean* to say by that?  Ordinarily, this notation would imply that $V$ is a vector.  You also seem to misuse the $\in$ symbol when writing $W_i \in V$.

Comment: [related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1865610/number-of-subspaces-that-contains-other-space/1865626#1865626)